# Best approach for multiple services

Tags: command-line, server

Warning: Linux newbie here

I got my first raspberry pi on which i would like to host  a number of things running concurrently. Pi is headless connected to wifi.

I'd like to have a couple of dashboards running... one of them is [Smashing](https://smashing.github.io/). Since these kind of services will take up the CLI screen, you cannot do anything else whilst a service is running.

What i did so far is, using Screen, I created a Screen, run the service and detach.
But this is giving me complications. Because I wanted the screens to run automatically when I boot (using crontab -e). The problem is that the Smashing command will not work. It will work when i do a screen manually, but when I set up a screen via Crontab I get PATH issues.

So my question is:

Am I approaching this correctly? Is Screen the way to go to:

- Run services in *separate* windows so that i can still use the CLI **that**
- can be configured to start as services on their own when rebooting?

I created a couple of scripts in a `/scripts/` folder one of them for example does:

```
echo "Looking up the Dashboard and running file"
ls
cd dashboard
ls
smashing start
echo "Operation completed."
```

This script should be called on boot via

`@reboot screen -dmS "dashboard" bash -c "./scripts/smashing.sh ;  bash"`

However it will not work because of some path issue:

`./scripts/smashing.sh: line 5: smashing: command not found`

This is weird because this will only happen if i launch the screen *via crontab on reboot.*
If i launch a screen myself, manually in the CLI, the service will load just fine.

Comment: how to you deal with auto start?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1030-raspi aarch64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation**: Let's disassemble the actual error output:

```
./scripts/smashing.sh: line 5: smashing: command not found
```

This means that on line 5 of the script, the interpreter found a command (`smashing`) that it could not locate a binary for.

You're right -- it's a $PATH issue. Cron is the other piece of the puzzle.

Cron does not use most of your environment variables when it runs jobs. This means that cron does not know about changes to **your** $PATH (changes like installing `smashing`).

This is a classic learning point for users new to cron jobs.

Old hands recommend always using full paths in cron jobs (and the scripts they trigger) for precisely this reason.

---

**Solution**: In your script, use a full path:

Use `whereis smashing` to learn the full path.

Then edit your script.

```
OLD:  smashing start
NEW:  /full/path/to/smashing start
```

Comment: is there anything else i need to add? `whereis smashing` works well. I got the path, and outside of screen it works well.

Inside screen, i don't get an error. but nothing happens.

Comment: I re-attached to the screen, and i tried to start. nothing happens. please see this pic: https://ibb.co/8DRk24M

Comment: btw the script is an .sh file

Comment: This must be related to cronjob. a new screen i created works fine.

Comment: i added sudo behind and it worked